# Parallelize C Code using SSE / AVX

Tags: c, x86, sse, simd, avx

i would like to parallelize my existing code using SSE/AVX Commands.
I am a complete noob to these instructions sets

the code snipper it is about is the following

```
static void inline enc_round(uint32_t b0[4], uint32_t b1[4], const uint32_t **kpp)
{
    for (int n = 0; n<4; n++)
    {
        b0[n] = crypto_ft_tab[0][byte(b1[n], 0)] ^
            crypto_ft_tab[1][byte(b1[(n + 1) & 3], 1)] ^
            crypto_ft_tab[2][byte(b1[(n + 2) & 3], 2)] ^
            crypto_ft_tab[3][byte(b1[(n + 3) & 3], 3)] ^ *(*kpp + n);
    }
    *kpp += 4;
}
```

With the following type definitions

```
const uint32_t crypto_ft_tab[4][256]
static inline uint8_t byte(const uint32_t x, const unsigned n)
```

I would like to parallelize the logical ANDS

**EDIT: Sorry I meant the bitwise XORs**

Any suggestion what is the best way to start or whith which commands I should start?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any logical ANDs - I see bitwise XORs - is that what you mean ?

Comment: @PaulR maybe he meant the `(n + 1) & 3` part ?

Comment: Ah - the *bitwise* ANDs - maybe - the question could use some clarification.

Comment: @PaulR vOv yep... You could edit(again :) ) so that the question will be clearer (because there are obviously no logical `and`s at all).

Comment: Sure - I only edited the tags - I'll let the OP fix the content, as I'd only be guessing as to the real requirements.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit dizy writing the text yesterday. I of course meant the bitwise XORs

Comment: My main porblem is how do I fit the crypto_ft_tab in a register when one part of the crypto_ft_tab is 256bit  and there are four of them per crypto_ft_tab.
i think that a naive way would be to load each part of the crypto_ft_tab into one seperate register, thus then I will fill all 16 with the crypto_ft_tab parts and have no more registers left to operate with

Comment: 1) If this is AES, are you open to the possibility of using the native AES instructions? 2) You say AVX, but is this AVX1 or AVX2? In the case of AVX2, your adds, ANDs and LUT reads can _all_ be vectorized thanks in part to Haswell's `gather` operations (although those are not especially fast themselves). Or you might be able to use the SSE2 `pshufb`. 3) For the final XORs you'll need to do a log2(n)-stage sequence of shuffles and XORs to perform that reduction.

Answer (score 0):

In GCC and Visual Studio you can easily use the compiler intrinsic functions to generate SSE and AVX instructions.

A list of available instructions can be found on the Intel website here: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Using SSE2 this would look something like this:

```
// load values 1 to 4 as 16 byte blocks from the given addresses:
__m128i value1 = _mm_loadu_((__m128i*)address1);
__m128i value2 = _mm_loadu_((__m128i*)address2);
__m128i value3 = _mm_loadu_((__m128i*)address3);
__m128i value4 = _mm_loadu_((__m128i*)address4);
// build xor
__m128i result = _mm_xor_si128(value1, value2);
result = _mm_xor_si128(result, value3);
result = _mm_xor_si128(result, value4);
// store the result somewhere into memory
_mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)addressForResult);
```

Note that each __m128i variable holds an entire 16 byte vector of your data. Using AVX2 intrinsics you can even process your data in 32 byte blocks.